# Using INSERT with a PostgreSQL Database using Python

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to insert data into a PostgreSQL database table using Python.  I don't see any syntax errors but, for some reason, my data isn't getting inserted into the database.

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(connection)
cursor = conn.cursor()
items = pickle.load(open(pickle_file,"rb"))

for item in items:
    city = item[0]
    price = item[1]
    info = item[2]

    query =  "INSERT INTO items (info, city, price) VALUES (%s, %s, %s);"
    data = (info, city, price)

    cursor.execute(query, data)
```

Comment: You must commit data, like conn.commit()

Comment: For string interpolation you can now use: ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}') in place of (%s, %s, %s) above.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You have to commit the transaction.

```
conn.commit()
```

If there's no reason to think the transaction will fail, it's faster to commit after the for loop finishes.

Comment: np, i make the same mistake all the time ;)