# How to use variables to insert into tables from python to PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am new to both python and SQL.
What I want to do eventually is that user types a value to insert into a table in PostgreSQL.
I have tried a few methods I could find,

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-structure.html
- http://www.java2s.com/Code/PostgreSQL/Postgre-SQL/UsingavariableinanINSERT.htm

but I have not been able to successfully insert. 
This is what I have now:

```
import psycopg2
from config import config

def create_tables(a):
    """ create tables in the PostgreSQL database"""
    commands = (
        """
        SET num 10,
        INSERT INTO Hotel_A (date, Suite, StandardKing) VALUES ('2017-09-12', num, 3)
        """,
        """
        INSERT INTO Hotel_A (date, Suite, StandardKing) VALUES ('2017-09-29', 5, 3)
        """,
        """
        INSERT INTO Hotel_A (date, Suite, StandardKing) VALUES ('2017-09-23', 5, 3)
        """
        )

    conn = None

    try:
        # read the connection parameters
        params = config()
        # connect to the PostgreSQL server
        conn = psycopg2.connect(**params)
        cur = conn.cursor()

        # create table one by one
        for command in commands:
            cur.execute(command)

        # close communication with the PostgreSQL database server
        cur.close()
        # commit the changes
        conn.commit()

    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        print(error)

    finally:
        if conn is not None:
            conn.close()

HotelASuite = 10

if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_tables(HotelASuite)
```

I want to do num = HotelASuite that is my goal.

Thank you so much for your help!.
I am using Python 2.7 and PostgreSQL 9.6.

Comment: Could you please explain your question

Comment: Include the code in the question, not a link to it. In other words produce a [mcve]. Have a look at for example [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9075349/using-insert-with-a-postgresql-database-using-python) for how to use placeholders. And finally, never ever manually string format or concatenate values to queries.

Comment: so when I insert values like this,   INSERT INTO Hotel_A (date, Suite, StandardKing) VALUES ('2017-09-12', 5, 3), instead of writing actual values, I want to use variables. so I want it to look like INSERT INTO Hotel_A (date, Suite, StandardKing) VALUES (date, int1, int2) where date, int1, and int2 are actually 2017-09-12, 5, and 3. Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes. Have a look at the question linked in the previous comment. You're looking for placeholders. Also read the psycopg2 documentation on how to pass variables: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries. And once more, do not use any form of string formatting yourself. That includes f-strings, `str.format()`, and the old %-formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 var1 = "x"
 var2 = datetime.datetime.now()
 curs.execute("INSERT INTO sometable (col1, col2) VALUES (%s, %s)", (var1,var2))
```

See [the manual](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries)