# Sending Output of a Python Script into specific field

Tags: python, mysql

How can i send the output of a python script into a specific field in my DB.

i know how to insert records in table,

```
sql = """INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE(FIRST_NAME,
LAST_NAME, AGE, SEX, INCOME)
VALUES ('Mac', 'Mohan', 20, 'M', 2000)"""
```

But Suppose My Code is

```
a=10
b=10
c=a+b
```

How can i insert the value of c which is 20, into specific field.

Comment: Check out SQLAlchemy. https://www.sqlalchemy.org/

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9075349/using-insert-with-a-postgresql-database-using-python